# how to keep a value set from a cookie on refresh

Tags: jquery, html

I have modal with two options-- select: city 1 or city 2. If a user selects city one, city 1 is stored in cookie other wise if he selects city 2, then that will be stored in a cookie. The default value is "Change city".

This the function that is called everytime a user selects one of the city. On button click, this function is called.

html

```
<a class="header-text" id="set-city" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#changeCity">Change City</a>
```

Jquery

```
function selectCity(cityName) {
    cookieStore.set('city', cityName);
    if (cookieStore.get('city')) {
        $("#set-city").html(cityName);
    }
}
```

Now if I refresh the page, the original "change city will show up". Means it doesnt show the selected city anymore. How do i keep the cookie selected value in the html even after refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

Set the city name in drop down (Your options must have city name as value it it) on [$.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready) like,

```
$(function(){
    cookieStore.get('city') &&  // check if city name exists in city
         $("#select").val(cookieStore.get('city')); // then show city name as selected
});
```